# Why won't "vcredist_x86_2010_sp1.exe,Asia" let me installer SQLite?

Tags: .net, sqlite, x86, visual-c++, redistributable

Has anyone heard of this strange package named: **vcredist_x86_2010_sp1.exe,Asia** ?

I've grabbed the SQLite for DotNet installer from [sqlite.org](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki), but every time I run it, I get this weird dialog box that stops it from progressing any further.

It looks like this:
[image]

I mean I know what the vcredists are.. but what the heck is this specific package and why is it getting in my way? Googling it doesn't fetch any results either!

I'm on Windows 7 32bit with .NET 4 Full and Visual Studio 2010 Premium.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
m^e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installer. I would assume that the latest SQLite.Net library requires that you have Visual Studio 2010 updated with SP1.

Also, perhaps related, maybe not, but others have had problems installing parts of the SQLite components, such as the designer. Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/2011/06/04/SQLite+On+Visual+Studio+2010+Setup+Instructions.aspx) if that pops up.

Comment: Thanks j.w.r. I'm grabbing the SP1 installer right now.. and that blog post was certainly helpful, coz I tried to do something similar on my own when I was unable to install the latest version - but that's another story :D

Answer (score 1):

hey all i found some thing else

when i found this error

i download separate setup from microsoft

then i get to know that there error displays you have a newer version installed

so this might be the problem

use uniextract16.exe (universal extracter)

extract then install

coz setup will abort on installation failure of vcredist_x86_2010_sp1.exe